# No commit found for SHA while using cobertura in itag based event

Tags: github-actions

Here's my workflow:

```yaml
on:
  push:
     tags:        
       - '*' 
env:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: ${{ github.workspace }}/.pip
  DEPLOY: false
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      with:
          fetch-depth: 0
       
    - name: Setup Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Cache pip packages
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        key: python | "${{ runner.os }}" | requirements.txt
        restore-keys:
        path: ${{ env.PIP_CACHE_DIR }}
   
    - name: Install Python requirements
      run: pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Run tests
      run: |
        python -m pytest tests/ \
              --doctest-modules \
              --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml \
              --cov=. \
              --cov-report=xml
    
    - name: Publish Test Report
      if: success() || failure() # always run even if the previous step fails
      uses: mikepenz/action-junit-report@v3
      with:
         report_paths: '**/test-*.xml'
         
     - name: Publish code coverage results
       if: success() || failure()
       uses: 5monkeys/cobertura-action@master
       with:
         path: ${{ github.workspace }}/**/coverage.xml
         minimum_coverage: 75
```

While using the above workflow, we are getting this error:

> No commit found for SHA:0d6043a0d131e097a1f35a9d6f504dec3e913230

The same code works when we change the trigger mechanism on `push`branch basis while using on tag basis we found error.

What could be the possible reason?

The point is that we have a `release.sh` file. When we run that file in our local system it creates a new version in GitHub action that step is still working fine but pipeline get failed in this step.

and the main point we want to highlight while running release.sh we are seeing two commit id one that is showing as relevant commit is the actual commit whose record is available in commit history while the second commit showing in code coverage step has no record in GitHub.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you sure it's `on: tag` that you're using? That's not a valid event. See [Events that trigger workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows).

Comment: For tags, you need `push`. See [`on.push`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushbranchestagsbranches-ignoretags-ignore) and [Running your workflow only when a push of specific tags occurs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-workflow-only-when-a-push-of-specific-tags-occurs).

Comment: You can lint your workflow with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to find such syntax errors quickly and with proper details and hints.

Comment: see the above syntax that was typing mistake i apologize for that now let me know what correction is required if we removed the tag run it on branch basis we are not getting such errors.

Comment: Please add the checkout step in your question. You might need `fetch-depth: 0` for code coverage.

Comment: See https://github.com/5monkeys/cobertura-action/blob/master/.github/workflows/coverage.yml.

Comment: kindly see i have upload my complete code and let me know what changes is required

Comment: See https://github.com/5monkeys/cobertura-action/blob/18d911b62098eafd8b9db93d6c74194556cc3515/.github/workflows/coverage.yml#L14-L16. Apparently, you need to add `with: fetch-depth: 0` in your checkout step.

Comment: Hi Azeem done the same still pipeline failed at the same state with same error

Comment: kindly see the above screenshot where you can see the actual commit id is mentioned in Get-SHA step while in Publish code coverage result show diff commit id when we done git show in our local we get the same result with both commit id but we can't see the commit id mentioned in publish code coverage in github commit history

Comment: Just looked at the [source](https://github.com/5monkeys/cobertura-action/blob/18d911b62098eafd8b9db93d6c74194556cc3515/src/action.js#L12-L16) and this action seems to work specifically for pull requests. It's the first line of its [README](https://github.com/5monkeys/cobertura-action?tab=readme-ov-file#cobertura-action). You can test with `pull_request` event. Your use case seems to be different. I believe you've already created an [issue](https://github.com/5monkeys/cobertura-action/issues/89) for this. You may discuss your requirements directly there with the maintainer(s).

Comment: is there any other action or tool we can implement in github action to achieve our goal

Comment: You can search on the GHA [marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions).